# Magento 2: Re-order the Customer Account links

Tags: magento2, xml, customer-account, page-layouts

I'm trying to re-order the links in the Customer Account (mysite.com/customer/account/) of my site. I've created:

```
#app/design/frontend/Mike/sitename/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">

<body>

    <!-- Removes the My Credit Cards links successfully -->
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>

    <!-- Won't move the Newsletter Subscription link to the bottom of the nav bar! -->
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" after="-"/>

</body>
```

Any idea why it won't work? Is the order of the links set elsewhere in Magento – in the admin area and stored in the database, for example..? Is there a problem with the XML above?

I've cleaned all cache and have run `magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US` but it does nothing. As I've noted in the code snippet, the My Credit Cards link is removed successfully, but the Newsletter link doesn't move anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to move it by doing something not that obvious... I 'moved' the element from its original location, `customer_account_navigation`, and placed it back there, at the same time telling M2 to place it `after` everything else.

```
#app/design/frontend/Mike/sitename/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml 

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">

<body>

    <!-- Removed the My Credit Cards links -->
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>

    <!-- Now works! -->
    <move element="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" destination="customer_account_navigation" after="-" />

</body>
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

As of M2.2.6 there is a new block class that allows to directly adjust the postion on the links. Use

```
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```

to re-order existing links and

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-your-block-name">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/path</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Title</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">290</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

to position new links.

In any customer_account.xml in a module or theme